# JQL expression to select all epics that contain recently updated stories

Tags: jira, jql, jira-agile

Is it possible to structure a JQL expression to select all epics that contain stories updated within the last 2 days? If so, what would this expression look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible just the way you want it, but you can select all stories that have epic link and that are changed within the last 2 days. Then adding "Epic link" column to search results you can easily see which epic they belong to.

JQL:

```
issuetype = Story AND "Epic Link" is not EMPTY AND updatedDate >= -2d
```

If you really need this the way you asked, you could try to look into JQL Tricks Plugin https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks.jql-plugin/server/overview it may have this behaviour implemented.